# What version of Ubuntu fits on a CD-R?

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to find a version of Ubuntu that will fit on a CD-R (700mb) so that I can get it installed on this tower. (no usb boot option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) can fit in a CD-R

lubuntu (Intel x86) desktop CD - 683 MB

lubuntu 64-bit (AMD64) desktop CD - 694 MB

Answer (score 3):

If you have a good internet connection, you could install the minimal version of ubuntu first and then install all necessary packages once installed.

You can get help regarding burning it to a CD and installing it on this wiki page:

- [Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

With this you could even install the latest version of ubuntu (Trusty Tahr) on your system.

Comment: I did that, and I installed Ubuntu Desktop, but it's basically command line. I did sudo apt-get install unity but what else do I need to install to get ubuntu up to current?

Comment: @Michaeljwjr, you choose to install the desktop from the menu in the installer, or `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the newest version of Ubuntu is sized below 700 Mb. To get a Ubuntu version that is sized below 700 Mb, you must try Ubuntu 10.04.04 (Lucid Lynx).

Better you pay a few bucks more and get the latest Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) on a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Ubuntu 10.10 (Oneiric) here : http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/

After having it installed, open the file `/etc/apt/source.list` as root, delete its content and enter the following :

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Save it.

You will now be able to get the latest Oneiric update with the `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` command, or upgrade to the current LTS version (12.04 and 14.04) with the `sudo apt-get update && sudo do-release-upgrade` command.

Oneiric is not maintained anymore, use it at your own risk.